# How to disallow select from a nested resource in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app that is multi tenant.  It has resources for Account, Client, and Transactions. An Account has many Clients has many Transactions.  I want to make sure I can never accidentally do Client.find, Transaction.find, etc (everything must go through the_account.clients.find, or client.transactions.find, etc). I want to do this so I don't accidentally show the wrong users things from the wrong account by forgetting to first select on the Account.

Is there a way to disable the Client.find (Client.find_by_name, Client.find_by_etc) but still allow the_account.clients.find?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about completely disabling Client.find, but I'd probably put a method into the bottom of each of my Client and Transaction controllers to handle lookups. Here's what the Client code would look like:

```
def collection
  if current_user.admin?
    Client.all
  else
    current_user.account.clients
  end
end
```

Then, everywhere in my controller I'd ordinarily use `Client.find`, I'd substitute `collection` instead. Gets you all the right records without risk of over-exposure.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I would still have to make sure to call the collection instead of find so wouldn't be much better off than I am now..